# Rails 4 check for session variable before setting value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have a basic form, but after detecting some errors, I want the form value to remain.

This is the code I have in the view:

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, value: session[:unsaved_user]['first_name'] %>
```

Whenever the session variable is not set it will puke an error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

My question is how can I rewrite the value to only be used if it's key is set in the session?

EDIT: Also I am validating the data in the user controller, then redirecting back to this original signup route if it fails.  That's why I'm using sessions to get the submitting params back to the form.  If there's a different approach to doing this I would appreciate any suggestions.  I'm pretty new to rails.

Comment: `session[:unsaved_user]['first_name'] || ''` but you might want to consider a different approach.

Comment: Whenever `session[:unsaved_user]` isn't set at all, it throws an error.  That's what I'm trying to avoid.  `|| ''` doesn't work.

Comment: you can use `session[:unsaved_user]['first_name'] rescue ''`, but its pretty ugly. its better to use a helper, decorator, or just a simple variable

Comment: Tried `rescue ''` but the fields just disappeared now.

Comment: Sorry, typo; you need to check both for the existence of the unsaved_user *and* its field. I forget if it's `get` or `fetch`, but basically `session[:unsaved_user].andand.fetch('first_name')`. But I'd probably do something along the lines of a form object that you restore from the session in the controller instead, or persist it to the DB temporarily, etc.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work either.  Seems like a simple thing to use a ternary operator or something on the fly without having to create a helper etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, session[:unsaved_user]['first_name'] || ''